# How to use basic queues in laravel without a Job

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.3

I have worked with Queues in laravel which will Queue the Jobs. `php artisan queue:work` command will take jobs in queue and process it.

But, i want to use pure queue without a job, One process will push itnto queue and another process read from queue and process it.

Eg, in a login api request, i will push just email id to queue. There will be a background process running(not queue:work) which can read the queue enties(list of emails) and do some action with it.

So the i need a custom worker which can read from queue.

How to do this in laravel?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use queue-able events (with database queue driver or whatever).

Comment: As far as i know events will only trigger on same process, unless it is queable, queable event work same was as job.

Comment: Well exactly, you want to do some asynchronous work, fire event that is pushed to queue and let the worker do it for you. You dont need "job" class you will have "event" class with ShouldQueue interface. Isnt that what you are looking for? Make real life example.

Comment: No that is not what i am looking for, simply i want to push from one process and pop in another one.

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for [forking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)? Popular [package](https://packagist.org/packages/duncan3dc/fork-helper) for handle forking. It seems I dont understand, lets wait for others :D. I tried. (Real world example would help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible directly. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17083

By design laravel doesnt allow this. You can however try to implement a custom solution.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case, need to write custom queue drivers for it.